# How can I disable the connection successful message on H2O

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, h2o

I'm making an R notebook with H2O and I don't want the H2O "Connection Successful" message and accompanying info (see below) to show.

Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster:

H2O cluster uptime:

H2O cluster version:

H2O cluster version age:

H2O cluster name:

H2O cluster total nodes:

H2O cluster total memory:

H2O cluster total cores:

H2O cluster allowed cores:  4

H2O cluster healthy:

H2O Connection ip:

H2O Connection port:

H2O Connection proxy:

H2O Internal Security:

R Version:

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `include=FALSE` in the chunk options. That should prevent any output from printing.

````
```{r include=FALSE}
h2o.init()
```
````

Comment: I was also plotting in the same chunk, so I just moved the plots to a new chunk and so this works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to suppress all R output, you can use the `sink()` function.  Here is how that would look with `h2o.init()`:

```
> library(h2o)
> sink("/dev/null") 
> h2o.init()
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: This is also great! I didn't know about this before.

Comment: How  would you get rid of the remaining information printed? I.e., of
```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode) 
```

Comment: I use this in an Rnw file and nothing were                                                               
printed <<warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results='hide',eval=TRUE>>=
invisible(library(h2o))
suppressMessages(invisible(h2o.init()))
@